# How to avoid constant api calls in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, api, react-lifecycle

I need to call `fectchData` when there's no `testData` in context store or input `ur` is different from saved `testData[0].ur`.
But this constantly request API if there's `ur` has empty `testData`. Which condition will make trick?

```
componentDidMount() {
    const [state] = this.context;
    const { testData } = state;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      console.log("fetching data");
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      this.updateTestData();
    };

    if (testData === "" || testData[0]?.ur !== this.props.ur) fetchData();
  }
```

Comment: why you have defined your function and states inside `componentDidMount`? each time you call the setState, it causes rerendering and it will call your API again...

Comment: it sounds reasonable, then how to handle loading state without compnentDidMount?

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know the results:

```
const [state] = this.context;
    const { testData } = state;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      console.log("fetching data");
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      this.updateTestData();
    };

componentDidMount() {
    if (testData === "" || testData[0]?.ur !== this.props.ur) {
       fetchData();
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a class component, how to define variables outside of methods?